# Qt: Get previous typed char

Tags: qt

```
QTextCursor c = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
QChar cc = c.PreviousCharacter;
```

This produces no errors, but also no result (not sure what is stored in cc). I want to collect the previous typed char in QTextEdit, no matter where the cursor may be (e.g. not collect the last char in QTextEdit, but the last typed). Anybody? Thanks!

Update:

Finally got it. See code.

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
QString c = cursor.selectedText().right(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`QTextCursor::PreviousCharacter` is an enumeration, so you will just store the int value of PreviousCharacter in that enumeration. It's supposed to be used like this: `c.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousCharacter)` meaning "move the cursor to the previous character", meaning to the next character to the left if you're typing in a Western left-to-right script, vice versa in RTL (i.e. Arabic) scripts. It doesn't keep track of the letters you type. You probably need to implement a key event handler that logs the keypresses.

Comment: I have a key event (on_textEdit_textChanged), and have tested that it works (used a QMessageBox). But nothing really happens with `c.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousCharacter)`. The cursor stays in the same position. And nothing is stored if I write `QChar cc = c.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousCharacter);`

Comment: Why are you even trying to store anything returned from movePosition. It only returns a bool indicating whether the move was successful, i.e. if you are at the beginning of the buffer it will return false because it couldn't move further back, true if the move was successful. Are you reading the documentation, or just trying to guess what each function does?